# What "LE3CA" component is?

Tags: diodes, components, zener

After plugging the device to the wrong power supply, it doesn't work anymore. When I plug the good power supply, the alimentation voltage drop to 0V and the component LE3CA is really hot (shortcut maybe?).

Because this component is close to the power supply, I'd like to replace it, just in case it repairs my device. My problem is I didn't find the reference of the component (maybe a zener diode) and the product company doesn't want to tell me :(

You can see the component in the middle of the picture.

[image: board]

Comment: its a component made by Vishay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wager a guess and say it's a TVS from Vishay (the logo at the bottom), probably a  [SMBJ12A](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88392/smbj50a.pdf) (unidirectional).

[image: datasheet excerpt]

The 3CA is the date code. Which tells us: manufactured December 2013 in factory A (I don't know where A is). (based on this [document](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf#page=4))

To make it more clear how I came to that conclusion:

- cathode band -> unidirectional device (also in the second document)
- LE marking -> type code
- 3CA marking -> date code

A search with Vishay LE marking turned up the mentioned TVS. Looking at Zener diodes from Vishay in the SMA/SMB case turned up quite different type codes (Wx - Zx) so it's unlikely to be a Zener diode.

Comment: XY” 2 digits: For rectifiers and PAR TVS (TPSMA, TPSMB, TPSMB, TPSMC, and TA6F), Perhaps is not a transzorb. http://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it's bidirectional, I found this on the datasheet "For bi-directional devices use CA suffix"

Comment: @MarkoBuršič That is about the date code, which is 3 digits on that component. The component is manufactured 2013, December in factory A. --> For TRANSZORB®  TVS and Power Voltage-Regulating Diodes.

Comment: @David the document linked by Marko Bursic says: No cathode band marking for TVS bi-directional type. But your component clearly has a cathode band, so it's a unidirectional. Also the LE marking is for unidirectional TVS.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Its exatly in your attached datasheet, LE manufactured 2013 december.

Answer (score 1):

The PCB legend suggests a diode and clearly indicates a direction.

What kind of diode is another matter, but if it's for reverse polarity protection, then a general purpose diode (like a 1N4007 but in the correct package) would work. If it's a zener diode or some kind of TVS, you'd need to find the correct part.

[Vishay marking guide](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf) suggests (page 4) that the line 3CA (identified by Arsenal as a date code) is from December 2013, we still have to find the "LE" type code.

Page 8 of [this document](http://matthieu.benoit.free.fr/cross/competitive/general_semi/marking.pdf) shows "LE" as a unihdirectional SMBJ12A.